# Passing arrays between buttons Windows form app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, parameter-passing

I am working on creating an app and for the whole program to work I need to initialise two arrays at one event of a button click and then pass it to another button so that the calculations are made after the button is pressed. Do you have any ideas of how I would do the procedure described above.

Many thanks

Comment: Store the array as an instance field of your form's class

Comment: This might help with future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask